# Animation not working in tizen

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

My animations are not working in Tizen emulator. The same code is working fine in google chrome. I am using jquery plugin, html5, css3 with Tizen 1.0. Is any API available for this?
please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Do they run in the Web Simulator, can you please give more details ?

Comment: Could you please insert any details?

Comment: A code example would be perfect ;)

Answer (score 1):

standard keyframes wont work in Tizen try using webkit-keyframes

Answer (score 0):

As Chaitanya said, standard CSS keyframes don't work, Webkit ones do. You can just define both, the browser will choose the version that can be used. Also VelocityJS can be used on TIZEN.

From my experience not all CSS functionality is supported on TIZEN, so depending on what you utilize in your CSS block, I expect the web app can still be prevented from running. Basically, you cannot expect code from modern, popular browsers to just run on TIZEN's webkit based browser. It may require a clean reimplementation.